# Dynamic programming problems using iteration

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

I have spent a lot of time to learn about implementing/visualizing dynamic programming problems using iteration but I find it very hard to understand, I can implement the same using recursion with memoization but it is slow when compared to iteration.

Can someone explain the same by a example of a hard problem or by using some basic concepts. Like the matrix chain multiplication, longest palindromic sub sequence  and others. I can understand the recursion process and then memoize the overlapping sub problems for efficiency but I can't understand how to do the same using iteration.

Thanks!

Comment: This problem, as written, is a little broad. Can you give an example of a specific problem you tried to solve iteratively, how you solved it recursively, and what problem you ran into when trying to do it iteratively?

Comment: For example you can take the matrix chain multiplication http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/, see my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464887/dynamic-programming-matrix-chain-multiplication, I can't think how to maintain a dp matrix or top-down/bottom-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamic programming is all about solving the sub-problems in order to solve the bigger one. The difference between the recursive approach and the iterative approach is that the former is top-down, and the latter is bottom-up. In other words, using recursion, you start from the big problem you are trying to solve and chop it down to a bit smaller sub-problems, on which you repeat the process until you reach the sub-problem so small you can solve. This has an advantage that you only have to solve the sub-problems that are absolutely needed and using memoization to remember the results as you go. The bottom-up approach first solves all the sub-problems, using tabulation to remember the results. If we are not doing extra work of solving the sub-problems that are not needed, this is a better approach.

For a simpler example, let's look at the Fibonacci sequence. Say we'd like to compute `F(101)`. When doing it recursively, we will start with our big problem - `F(101)`. For that, we notice that we need to compute `F(99)` and `F(100)`. Then, for `F(99)` we need `F(97)` and `F(98)`. We continue until we reach the smallest solvable sub-problem, which is `F(1)`, and memoize the results. When doing it iteratively, we start from the smallest sub-problem, `F(1)` and continue all the way up, keeping the results in a table (so essentially it's just a simple for loop from 1 to 101 in this case).

Let's take a look at the matrix chain multiplication problem, which you requested. We'll start with a naive recursive implementation, then recursive DP, and finally iterative DP. It's going to be implemented in a C/C++ soup, but you should be able to follow along even if you are not very familiar with them.

```
/* Solve the problem recursively (naive)

   p - matrix dimensions
   n - size of p
   i..j - state (sub-problem): range of parenthesis */
int solve_rn(int p[], int n, int i, int j) {
    // A matrix multiplied by itself needs no operations
    if (i == j) return 0;

    // A minimal solution for this sub-problem, we
    // initialize it with the maximal possible value
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    // Recursively solve all the sub-problems
    for (int k = i; k < j; ++k) {
        int tmp = solve_rn(p, n, i, k) + solve_rn(p, n, k + 1, j) + p[i - 1] * p[k] * p[j];
        if (tmp < min) min = tmp;
    }

    // Return solution for this sub-problem
    return min;
}
```

To compute the result, we starts with the big problem:

```
solve_rn(p, n, 1, n - 1)
```

The key of DP is to remember all the solutions to the sub-problems instead of forgetting them, so we don't need to recompute them. It's trivial to make a few adjustments to the above code in order to achieve that:

```
/* Solve the problem recursively (DP)

   p - matrix dimensions
   n - size of p
   i..j - state (sub-problem): range of parenthesis */
int solve_r(int p[], int n, int i, int j) {
    /* We need to remember the results for state i..j.
       This can be done in a matrix, which we call dp,
       such that dp[i][j] is the best solution for the
       state i..j. We initialize everything to 0 first.

       static keyword here is just a C/C++ thing for keeping
       the matrix between function calls, you can also either
       make it global or pass it as a parameter each time.

       MAXN is here too because the array size when doing it like
       this has to be a constant in C/C++. I set it to 100 here.
       But you can do it some other way if you don't like it. */
    static int dp[MAXN][MAXN] = {{0}};

    /* A matrix multiplied by itself has 0 operations, so we
       can just return 0. Also, if we already computed the result
       for this state, just return that. */
    if (i == j) return 0;
    else if (dp[i][j] != 0) return dp[i][j];

    // A minimal solution for this sub-problem, we
    // initialize it with the maximal possible value
    dp[i][j] = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    // Recursively solve all the sub-problems
    for (int k = i; k < j; ++k) {
        int tmp = solve_r(p, n, i, k) + solve_r(p, n, k + 1, j) + p[i - 1] * p[k] * p[j];
        if (tmp < dp[i][j]) dp[i][j] = tmp;
    }

    // Return solution for this sub-problem
    return dp[i][j];;
}
```

We start with the big problem as well:

```
solve_r(p, n, 1, n - 1)
```

Iterative solution is only to, well, iterate all the states, instead of starting from the top:

```
/* Solve the problem iteratively

   p - matrix dimensions
   n - size of p

   We don't need to pass state, because we iterate the states. */
int solve_i(int p[], int n) {
    // But we do need our table, just like before
    static int dp[MAXN][MAXN];

    // Multiplying a matrix by itself needs no operations
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        dp[i][i] = 0;

    // L represents the length of the chain. We go from smallest, to
    // biggest. Made L capital to distinguish letter l from number 1
    for (int L = 2; L < n; ++L) {
        // This double loop goes through all the states in the current
        // chain length.
        for (int i = 1; i <= n - L + 1; ++i) {
            int j = i + L - 1;
            dp[i][j] = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

            for (int k = i; k <= j - 1; ++k) {
                int tmp = dp[i][k] + dp[k+1][j] + p[i-1] * p[k] * p[j];
                if (tmp < dp[i][j])
                    dp[i][j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the result of the biggest problem
    return dp[1][n-1];
}
```

To compute the result, just call it:

```
solve_i(p, n)
```

---

Explanation of the loop counters in the last example:

Let's say we need to optimize the multiplication of 4 matrices: `A B C D`. We are doing an iterative approach, so we will first compute the chains with the length of two: `(A B) C D`, `A (B C) D`, and `A B (C D)`. And then chains of three: `(A B C) D`, and `A (B C D)`. That is what `L`, `i` and `j` are for.

`L` represents the chain length, it goes from `2` to `n - 1` (`n` is `4` in this case, so that is `3`).

`i` and `j` represent the starting and ending position of the chain. In case `L = 2`, `i` goes from `1` to `3`, and `j` goes from `2` to `4`:

```
(A B) C D     A (B C) D     A B (C D)
 ^ ^             ^ ^             ^ ^
 i j             i j             i j
```

In case `L = 3`, `i` goes from `1` to `2`, and `j` goes from `3` to `4`:

```
(A B C) D     A (B C D)
 ^   ^           ^   ^
 i   j           i   j
```

So generally, `i` goes from `1` to `n - L + 1`, and `j` is `i + L - 1`.

Now, let's continue with the algorithm assuming that we are at the step where we have `(A B C) D`. We now need to take into account the sub-problems (which are already calculated): `((A B) C) D` and `(A (B C)) D`. That is what `k` is for. It goes through all the positions between `i` and `j` and computes the sub problems.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Can you explain the loops in the last code,  why the 2nd loop is upto n - L +1 and how j is calculated and the 3rd loop i to j-1. With a example perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with recursion is the high number of stack frames that need to be pushed/popped. This can quickly become the bottle-neck.

The Fibonacci Series can be calculated with iterative DP or recursion with memoization. If we calculate F(100) in DP all we need is an array of length 100 e.g. `int[100]` and that's the guts of our used memory. We calculate all entries of the array pre-filling `f[0]` and `f[1]` as they are defined to be `1`. and each value just depends on the previous two.

If we use a recursive solution we start at `fib(100)` and work down. Every method call from 100 down to 0 is pushed onto the stack, **AND** checked if it's memoized. These operations add up and iteration doesn't suffer from either of these. In iteration (bottom-up) we already know all of the previous answers are valid. The bigger impact is probably the stack frames; and given a larger input you may get a `StackOverflowException` for what was otherwise trivial with an iterative DP approach.